# datetime.datetime' object is not callable python

Tags: python, api, time, fastapi

I am currently working on an API which is using FastAPI, it is mainly used for adding sensor data into my mongodb database. I also want to add a timestamp (for CET) which is automatically written into the mongodb database with the sensor data.

```
class DataModel(BaseModel):
    id: PyObjectId = Field(default_factory=PyObjectId, alias="_id")
    loc: str
    sensor: str
    temp: float
    humi: float
    press: float
    power: float
    timestamp: datetime = Field(default_factory=(datetime.utcnow()+timedelta(hours=1)))

    class Config:
        allow_population_by_field_name = True
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True
        json_encoders = {ObjectId: str}
```

Everything is working fine except the timestamp.
This error occurs:

```
{
    "detail": [
        {
            "loc": [
                "body"
            ],
            "msg": "'datetime.datetime' object is not callable",
            "type": "type_error"
        }
    ]
}
```

I hope you have an idea what the possible problem could be.

```
    {
        "_id": "637b80a052feee6809711f2c",
        "loc": "Mödling",
        "sensor": "BME680",
        "temp": 5.0,
        "humi": 60.0,
        "press": 1000.0,
        "timestamp": "2022-11-21T13:44:00.371512"
    },
```

This is the output when im only using datetime.utcnow without the brackets and without the timedelta.
When I am using datetime.utcnow() without the timedelta the same problem occurs.

Comment: If `datetime.utcnow` (without parentheses) results in a datetime object then it sounds like you have replaced or somehow shadowed datetime.utcnow somewhere in your code. Show how you're importing datetime.

Comment: from datetime import datetime, timedelta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`default_factory` should be a function, and you are giving a `datetime.datetime` type

Do a lambda function:

```
timestamp: datetime = Field(default_factory= lambda : (datetime.utcnow()+timedelta(hours=1)))
```